# Show that $\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{y^2}{(y-1)^2} + \frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}\ge 1$ for real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ with $xyz=1$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, factoring, substitution

I've been thinking to prove each one individually then sum them up which seems too complex to because I haven't made any notable success proving $\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}> 1$.

I know that $(x-1)^2\ge 0$ , but I'm not able to transfer it to what I'm looking to prove.

Is there is any techniques to look for when solving these kind of inequalities because I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: You have an extra $($.  Do you mean $\dfrac{x^2}{(x-1)^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{(y-1)^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}$?

Comment: And if $x$, $y$ or $z$ is $1$, it is undefined.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thats right.

Comment: @Richard sorry meant real numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{b}{c}$ and $z=\frac{c}{a}$

Hence,$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}-1=\frac{(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a-3abc)^2}{(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2}\geq0.$$

Comment: Is this formula factorized manually??

Comment: Yes, of course. I make it by hand. It's a work with cyclic sums.

Comment: That's really a wonderful job!

Comment: We need to know that $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2=\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b^2-a^3b^3-a^4bc+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2).$ I proved this inequality $11$ years ago. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h113999

Answer (score 0):

If
$x=1+a, y=1+b, z=1+c$
then
$a, b, c \ge 0$
since all are positive integers
and

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^2}{(x-1)^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{(y-1)^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}
&=\dfrac{(1+a)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(1+b)^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{(1+c)^2}{c^2}\\
&=1+\dfrac{1+2a}{a^2} +1+ \dfrac{1+2b}{b^2} +1+ \dfrac{1+2c}{c^2}\\
&=3+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+ \dfrac{1}{b^2}+ \dfrac{1}{c^2}+2(\dfrac{1}{a}+ \dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{c})\\
&\ge 3\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: $xyz=1$ does not rule out the chance that $x<0$ and so $a<0$.

Comment: "since all are positive integers"  Um... what???? Where on earth did you get *that* idea.  Unless they are all equal to 1, xyz = 1 most certainly means they are *not* positive integers.

Comment: Not only does xyz = 1  not rule out that $x < 0$ unless x,y,z are all equal it *assures* some of the a,b,c *must* be negative.

Comment: @fleablood Check the edit history, the original question asked, by mistake, for integer solutions.

Comment: Um,  No...https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2592422/revisions nowhere in the original post were integers asked for which would have *obviously* have been impossible. unless $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$.

Comment: @fleablood It quite clearly says positive integers in the very first post....

Comment: @fleablood Quoting the OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2592422/1): `prove this inequality hold if x,y,z is positive integer`.